# SQL SP - Case statement in Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, case, where-clause

In the following table

```
 ID     AMT
 -------------
 347    0.00
 575    725.00
 362    125.00
 540    80.00
```

I want to use a case statement in a where clause to filter the results based on two input parameters for my stored proc. Here is how my SP looks like

```
 CREATE PROC SS(@AMT_GREATER_THAN INT, @AMT_LESS_THAN INT)
 AS
 BEGIN
     SELECT ID, AMT FROM TABLE
     WHERE 
     1 = CASE WHEN @AMT_GREATER_THAN IS NOT NULL AND @AMT_LESS_THAN IS NOT 
                   NULL AND AMT BETWEEN @AMT_LESS_THAN AND @AMT_GREATER_THAN 
                   THEN 1
              WHEN @AMT_GREATER_THAN IS NOT NULL AND AMT > @AMT_GREATER_THAN 
                   THEN 1
              WHEN @AMT_LESS_THAN IS NOT NULL AND AMT < @AMT_LESS_THAN 
                   THEN 1
              ELSE 0 END
 END
```

When I execute the SP I'm expecting the output to be

```
     EXEC SS 50, 150 //OUTPUT should be 80 and 125
     EXEC SS null, 150 //OUTPUT should be 0, 80 and 125
     EXEC SS 50, null//OUTPUT should be 80 and 125, 725
```

But what I'm getting is all four AMT column values, can anyone point me where the issue is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` constructions instead of `case` _expressions_ in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: `@AMT_LESS_THAN IS NOT NULL AND AMT < @AMT_LESS_THAN` can be simplified as `AMT < @AMT_LESS_THAN`, since the `<` comparison will never be _true_ for null values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip the `case` *expression*, use `and`/`or` instead:

```
 SELECT ID, AMT FROM TABLE
 WHERE (AMT < @AMT_GREATER_THAN  OR  @AMT_GREATER_THAN IS NULL)
   AND (AMT > @AMT_LESS_THAN     OR  @AMT_LESS_THAN IS NULL)
```

Perhaps you want `>=` and `<=`? (The `GREATER_THAN` and `LESS_THAN` names act the opposite in your query. Which one has the higher value?)

Comment: yes, I would like to have >= and <=, but I got like 20 odd input parameters for the SP which I need to filter in the where clause, so I opted for CASE statement. Is there a way to do it in CASE ?

Comment: Avoid case expressions in the where clause, you gain nothing but loose performance since they are hard to optimize. Take a look at my query and simply add `AND (col = @param  or  @param is null)` for each param.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the query below to simplify:

```
 SELECT ID, AMT FROM TABLE
 WHERE (@AMT_GREATER_THAN IS NOT NULL AND @AMT_LESS_THAN IS NOT 
           NULL AND AMT BETWEEN @AMT_LESS_THAN AND @AMT_GREATER_THAN)
    OR (@AMT_GREATER_THAN IS NOT NULL AND AMT > @AMT_GREATER_THAN)
    OR (@AMT_LESS_THAN IS NOT NULL AND AMT < @AMT_LESS_THAN)
```